# Фильтрация при двойном агрегировании elasticsearch

Tags: php, elasticsearch, aggregation-framework

Я делаю вот такую агригацию:

```
{
"aggs": {
    "characteristics": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "product_char.char_id"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "value": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "product_char.value.keyword"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

И хочу получить уникальное значение конкретной характеристики, но вместо этого в `value` я получаю все возможные значения всех характеристик вместе взятых. Как сделать так, что бы в каждой уникальной `characteristics` был свой набор уникальных `value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Крч если кому надо)) делаете маппинг, ставите у `product_char` тип `nested` (это если у вас как у меня массив объектов внутри product_char, если один объект то и так должно всё работать).
Код аггригации для nested такой:

```
{
 "aggs": {
   "characteristics": {
     "nested": {
       "path": "product_char"
     },
     "aggs": {
       "char_ids": {
         "terms": {
           "field": "product_char.id",
                     "size": 1000000
         },
         "aggs": {
           "values": {
             "terms": {
               "field": "product_char.value.keyword",
               "size": 1000000
             }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
}
```

p/s Спасибо комьюнити, ELASTIC СДЕЛАЙ НОРМ ДОКУМЕНТАЦИЮ!!